# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I try to implement firebase auth anonymous and i am getting the following error:

**I/flutter (11251): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null.
I/flutter (11251): Receiver: null
I/flutter (11251): Tried calling: call(Instance of 'User')**

**pubspec.yaml:**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: 0.5.1
  firebase_auth: 0.18.2
```

Part of my **main.dart:**

```
...
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LandingPage(), // SplashScreen
    ); // define it once at root level.
  }
}
...
...
...


class ExcRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  const Exc({Key key, @required this.onSignIn}) : super(key: key);
  final void Function(User) onSignIn;

  Future<void> _signInAnonymously() async {
    try {
      final userCredentials = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
      onSignIn(userCredentials.user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
```

my **landing_page.dart:**

````
import 'package:exc/main.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // const LandingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  User _user;

  void _updateUser(User user) {
    setState(() {
      _user = user;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_user == null) {
      return ExcRoute(
        onSignIn: _updateUser,
      );
    }
    return Container();
  }
}```
````

Comment: Did you enable Anonymous accounts in the Auth section of the Firebase console before being able to use them?

Comment: yes of course i have enabled it

Answer (score 0):

The error `NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null.` points to User. It's likely that you're trying to call an instance of the User object even if it's null. You may want to check if `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();` successfully logs-in. It's likely that the error occurs on this part. A simple null check should be a good workaround for this issue.

```dart
final userCredentials = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
if(userCredentials != null) {
  onSignIn(userCredentials.user);
}
```